# Error in using XML data type

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<Root>
          <row id="1"><name>Larry</name><oflw>some text</oflw></row>
          <row id = "2"><name>moe</name></row>
          <row id = "3"/>
          </Root>'
 select T.c.query(..) as result from @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(C)

select T.c.query(..) as result from @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(C)
```

I am getting following error.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

could any one help me correcting the error. I am new to sql .

Comment: @gbn : i have edited t question. please go through now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should one this:

```
select T.c.query('..') as result from @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(C)
```

or maybe

```
select T.c.query('.') as result from @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(C)
```

The path parameter to the `query` method should be a string

Answer (score 0):

Not sure **what** you're trying to extract from your XML - but try this query - it will "take apart" all the bits of information stored in the XML and show them as separate values:

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<Root>
          <row id="1"><name>Larry</name><oflw>some text</oflw></row>
          <row id="2"><name>moe</name></row>
          <row id="3"/>
          </Root>'

select 
    T.c.value('@id', 'int') as 'ID', 
    T.c.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(25)') as result,
    T.c.value('(oflw)[1]', 'varchar(25)') as 'OFlw'
from @x.nodes('/Root/row') T(C)
```

Output:

```
ID  result  OFlw
1   Larry   some text
2   moe     NULL
3   NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I got know how to use value() method.

Comment: Could u please explain me tha usage of node().

Comment: It creates an "in-memory" list / pseudo table of XML nodes, based on the XPath provided - here, it creates a list of all `<row>` nodes in the `<Root>` parent node. You can then use those to grab individual values from each node, as if it were a table with XML values inside it